# How do you clean up a text background with Gimp?

Tags: gimp

This is my first post here, I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I am in the process of cleaning up some text in a document with gimp, and how I'm doing it is by painting out the pixels between the text with a white paint/paint brush. It works, but it is time consuming. I just wanted to ask if there might be an easier way to do this. I've attached a screen shot showing what I'm talking about.

[image: screenshot of gimp window]

In the screen shot, you can see some text where I have zoomed in to make it larger. I am enlarging the text, then painting out all of the dark pixels that were left from when the image was scanned. Is there an easier way with gimp ?

Comment: Thise Q&A may help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/638382/how-can-i-turn-photos-of-paper-documents-into-a-scanned-document

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do it in [Photopea](https://www.Photopea.com) (I made Photopea), but it is probably the same in all programs.

Choose Magic Wand (Fuzzy selection) and click on the area that you want to remove (try different values of Tolerance). Now you can fill the selection with the white color (Edit - Fill, or paint with a large brush).

Another way is using [Levels](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-levels.html) (Ctrl + L or Image - Adjustments - Levels). Drag the right-side limit (for whites) to the left to make almost-white colors completely white. I just tried it on your image:

[image: your screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried the  levels adjustment, which got me to where I am now. So, I'll give the magic wand a try, and see how that works out. I think that even painting it white is OK, I'm likely not using the most optimum adjustments to paint out the grey areas.